# aiobotocore s3 file upload it seems things not getting through

Tags: boto3, aiohttp, botocore

I am uploading an image and its thumb to an s3-bucket using simple aiobotocore usecase. Traceback is below. It seems things are not getting through. Could someone help sorting out whats went wrong here. Iam using aiohttp with this usecase.

```
session = aiobotocore.get_session()
async with session.create_client('s3', region_name='ap-south-1',
                        aws_secret_access_key=key,
                        aws_access_key_id=id) as client:
                                         
    img_resp = await client.put_object(Bucket=bucket,
                                        Key=key_img,
                                        Body=img)
                                
     thumb_resp = await client.put_object(Bucket=bucket,
                                        Key=key_thumb,
                                        Body=thumb)
return {img_resp, thumb_resp}
```

Traceback: Seems nothing convincing to me

```
2020-07-28 13:19:03,834 DEBUG botocore.hooks Changing event name from creating-client-class.iot-data to creating-client-class.iot-data-plane
2020-07-28 13:19:03,838 DEBUG botocore.hooks Changing event name from before-call.apigateway to before-call.api-gateway
2020-07-28 13:19:03,839 DEBUG botocore.hooks Changing event name from request-created.machinelearning.Predict to request-created.machine-learning.Predict
2020-07-28 13:19:03,840 DEBUG botocore.hooks Changing event name from before-parameter-build.autoscaling.CreateLaunchConfiguration to before-parameter--domain.Search.complete-section
2020-07-28 13:19:03,850 DEBUG aiobotocore.credentials Looking for credentials via: env, .....
2020-07-28 13:19:03,860 DEBUG botocore.utils Metadata service returned non-200 response with status code of 404 for url: http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/, content body: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>404 - Not Found</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>404 - Not Found</h1>
 </body>
</html>

2020-07-28 13:19:03,861 DEBUG aiobotocore.utils Max number of attempts exceeded (1) when attempting to retrieve data from metadata service.
2020-07-28 13:19:03,862 DEBUG botocore.loaders Loading JSON file: /home/ubuntu/app/aioenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/data/endpoints.json
2020-07-28 13:19:03,872 DEBUG botocore.hooks Event choose-service-name: calling handler <function handle_service_name_alias at 0x7fbd66934950>
2020-07-28 13:19:03,879 DEBUG botocore.loaders Loading JSON file: /home/ubuntu/app/aioenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/data/s3/2006-03-01/service-2.json
2020-07-28 13:19:03,893 DEBUG botocore.endpoint Setting s3 timeout as (60, 60)
2020-07-28 13:19:03,894 DEBUG botocore.loaders Loading JSON file: /home/ubuntu/app/aioenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/data/_retry.json
2020-07-28 13:19:03,894 DEBUG botocore.client Registering retry handlers for service: s3
2020-07-28 13:19:03,896 DEBUG botocore.hooks Event before-parameter-build.s3.PutObject: calling handler <function validate_ascii_metadata at 0x7fbd668d2c80>
2020-07-28 13:19:03,896 DEBUG botocore.hooks Event before-parameter-build.s3.PutObject: calling handler <function sse_md5 at 0x7fbd668d2158>
2020-07-28 13:19:03,897 DEBUG botocore.hooks Event before-parameter-build.s3.PutObject: calling handler <function convert_body_to_file_like_object at 0x7fbd668d4598>
2020-07-28 13:19:03,897 DEBUG botocore.hooks Event before-parameter-build.s3.PutObject: calling handler <function validate_bucket_name at 0x7fbd668d20d0>
2020-07-28 13:19:03,897 DEBUG botocore.hooks Event before-parameter-build.s3.PutObject: calling handler <bound method S3RegionRedirector.redirect_from_cache of <botocore.utils.S3RegionRedirector object at 0x7fbd54409a20>>
2020-07-28 13:19:03,897 DEBUG botocore.hooks Event before-parameter-build.s3.PutObject: calling handler <bound method S3ArnParamHandler.handle_arn of <botocore.utils.S3ArnParamHandler object at 0x7fbd543c3080>>
2020-07-28 13:19:03,898 DEBUG botocore.hooks Event before-parameter-build.s3.PutObject: calling handler <function generate_idempotent_uuid at 0x7fbd66943c80>
2020-07-28 13:19:03,898 DEBUG botocore.hooks Event before-call.s3.PutObject: calling handler <function conditionally_calculate_md5 at 0x7fbd668d2048>
2020-07-28 13:19:03,899 DEBUG botocore.hooks Event before-call.s3.PutObject: calling handler <function add_expect_header at 0x7fbd668d2400>
2020-07-28 13:19:03,899 DEBUG botocore.handlers Adding expect 100 continue header to request.
2020-07-28 13:19:03,899 DEBUG botocore.hooks Event before-call.s3.PutObject: calling handler <bound method S3RegionRedirector.set_request_url of <botocore.utils.S3RegionRedirector object at 0x7fbd54409a20>>
2020-07-28 13:19:03,900 DEBUG botocore.hooks Event before-call.s3.PutObject: calling handler <function inject_api_version_header_if_needed at 0x7fbd668d46a8>
2020-07-28 13:19:03,900 DEBUG botocore.endpoint Making request for OperationModel(name=PutObject) with params: {'url_path': '/c-pix/imgs/d6ef8.jpg', 'query_string': {}, 'method': 'PUT', 'headers': {'x-amz-meta-mappuser': '63bd1', 'User-Agent': 'Botocore/1.15.32 Python/3.6.9 Linux/5.3.0-1030-aws', 'Content-MD5': '8fgw==', 'Expect': '100-continue'}, 'body': <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7fbd543c2258>, 'url': 'https://s3.cc.com/cpix/imgs/c6ef8.jpg', 'context': {'client_region': 'ap-south-1', 'client_config': <aiobotocore.config.AioConfig object at 0x7fbd544095c0>, 'has_streaming_input': True, 'auth_type': None, 'signing': {'bucket': 'cr-pix'}}}
2020-07-28 13:19:03,901 DEBUG botocore.hooks Event request-created.s3.PutObject: calling handler <bound method AioRequestSigner.handler of <aiobotocore.signers.AioRequestSigner object at 0x7fbd54409588>>
2020-07-28 13:19:03,901 DEBUG botocore.hooks Event choose-signer.s3.PutObject: calling handler <function set_operation_specific_signer at 0x7fbd66943b70>
2020-07-28 13:19:03,901 DEBUG botocore.hooks Event before-sign.s3.PutObject: calling handler <bound method S3EndpointSetter.set_endpoint of <botocore.utils.S3EndpointSetter object at 0x7fbd543c30f0>>
2020-07-28 13:19:03,902 DEBUG botocore.utils Defaulting to S3 virtual host style addressing with path style addressing fallback.
2020-07-28 13:19:03,902 DEBUG botocore.utils Checking for DNS compatible bucket for: https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/c-pix/imgs/c0d6ef8.jpg
2020-07-28 13:19:03,902 DEBUG botocore.utils URI updated to: https://c-pix.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/imgs/c0d6ef8.jpg
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: From the error trace, it looks the program isn't using the AWS keys you have set and instead it's querying for the Metadata instance service on the EC2 machine 


`http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/`


Metadata service returned non-200 response. You should check your validity of keys once.

Comment: @Shivankar this key was working perfectly with development server.

Comment: ok you could try configuring the keys by running `aws configure` and then try executing the program?
What exactly is the error, are the files not being uploaded?

Comment: @Shivankar files are not uploaded and my upstream server debug trace says its stuck there and not evicting any response.

Comment: @Shivankar, I am not using awscli